# The opposite to index()?

Tags: python, indexing

If I were to write the following:

```
s = 'abcdefh'
print s.index(c)
```

I would get 2. However, I want to do the opposite, i.e. know the index number and get the corresponding letter printed (In other words, I know the index number 2 and want the letter 'c' printed).

Comment: First read the tutorial (https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/), then ask questions...

Comment: Seems simple: `next(char for index, char in enumerate(s) if index == 2)` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The operation is called indexing. That's why `s.index()` is called `s.index()`.

```
print s[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of `index` would be to use the `[]` operator:

```
>>> s = 'abcdefh'
>>> s[2]
'c'
```